# tfs build not copying latest config files to drop folder

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfsbuild

I have several config files in different projects in my master solution that are set to "**Copy if newer**" that tfs build is not getting the latest for on each build.

I currently have the build configuration option "**Clean Workspace**" set to "**All**".  I would think it would be copying the latest files from TFS but it is not.  It is getting prior versions.

Furthermore the build folders on my local machine reflect the latest files from TFS.  Is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem and it didn't have anything to do with TFS.  I had multiple versions of the same config file in various projects within my solution.

To correct this I added a single configuration file at the solution level and added it as a linked file in all the projects where I needed it.

[How to Share App.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426245/how-to-share-app-config)

Comment: my problem is that bin folder is created but the updated build dll is not get complied  and not placed into the artifact, instead I manually check Out the .dll file and than checkIn and after that my changes appears