# Database connection from web.config in other project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am strugling to get the proper/best way to handle a connection string in an other project:

I have two projects in a VS solution:

1. Project 1: website (asp.net)

   - with web.config has a db connection string
2. Project 2: with some classes

   - with data layer (to be accessed in project 1 or project x)

What is the proper way to set the connection string in project 2?

Project 2 has a static class with function like:

```
public static List<T> GetData();
```

Should I always pass the connection string as an variable like:

```
public static List<T> GetData(string connectionString);
```

So syntax like i.e.:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"];
var list = ClassX.GetData(connectionString);
```

Or is it possible to set in general somewhere in an other way?

Or is my complete setup wrong? :)

Comment: Is project 2 a class library ?

Comment: are you using EDMX in service layers?

Comment: use a common class with common method in project 2 where get the connection string from own project then add reference to project and just call this method

Comment: yes it is a class library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class libraries do not have their own configuration. They use the configuration of which ever executable they are being used in.

This means that for you you should be able to use the same code, and it will read the setting from the config (assuming that it is there).

Answer (score 2):

We usually put the `connection string` in the website (**Main Entry Point**), and we can read it from the `class library` (Project 2).

Just add a reference for `System.Configuration` in your class library and you're good to go and read the `config` from project 1 as if you're executing the code in project 1 directly.

Answer (score 1):

Some good ways described are as:

Put common configuration settings in `machine.config` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697.aspx)

Also look at this which shows how to share same app.config file (assume you can place connection string in this) between multiple project in the same solution.

[Sharing App.config between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426245/how-to-share-app-config)

Comment: We use machine.config for common configuration items (including connection strings) too.

Comment: @Moose, thanks for supporting it. I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not important to define a connection string in both projects, just add in on your config file of **Project 1: website (asp.net)** that is your default project.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="Server=ServerName; User ID=sa; Password=123; Database = DBName;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

more information on : http://www.connectionstrings.com/